# Show a page when OK button of push notification is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I want to show `thanku.html` page when the user provides Push Notifications permission (ie. when user taps on OK button to allow the notifications).
This page should be displayed only once.

Problem faced:

1. `thanku.htlml` page reloads in background before pressing the OK button.
2. If notifications permission is accepted, `thanku.html` page opens every time the app is launched. Whereas, it should not be displayed on relaunch.

Code I have written:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    // For show the thank you page
    NSArray *controllers = [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].viewControllers;

    for (id obj in controllers) {
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]])
        {
            ViewController *controller = (ViewController *)obj;

            controller.titleOfController = @"Thank you";
            controller.urlStr = @"http://www.7dci.com.au/lagarto/thankyou.html";
            [controller showAtAppearTime];

            [[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
            return;
        }
    }

    ViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil ] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    controller.titleOfController = @"Thank you";
    controller.urlStr = @"http://www.7dci.com.au/lagarto/thankyou.html";
    [controller showAtAppearTime];
    [[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

In `viewdidload` of view controller:

```
 [self showAtAppearTime];
```

and the `showAtAppearTime` is:

```
- (void)showAtAppearTime
{
    [webView setDelegate:self];

    [self setEmptyWebview];

    titleLbl.text = @"saurabh";
    if(self.titleOfController.length > 0)
        titleLbl.text = self.titleOfController;
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://7dci.com.au/lagarto/menu.html";
    if(self.urlStr.length > 0)
        urlAddress = self.urlStr;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

and the `setEmptyWebview` is

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Are you sending a PushNotification *ONCE* per app installation? Do you only want to show the "ThankYou.html" web page *ONCE* per app installation?

Comment: Yes, but I am unable to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
if(![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isFirstTime"] isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"isFirstTime"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    //Write your required code to set html here
} }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Sir This is working for me..means when i clicked on ok then thanku.html page shows. and another time of launch it does not shows. But i find that first time when install the app the the thankyou.html page already download on behind of the pop up

Comment: and Sir I find my app will my application always get inside this method – application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: at launch time? when i pressed do not allow at that time this mehod also called